# How to add bitcode to Xcode framework/project?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, arm64, bitcode

I want to enable bitcode in my project as well a framework. I know how to enable it but question is how to add it so that my Project do contain bitcode. I am having issue with archiving where the project is bitcode enabled so as the framework it is using BUT the framework is not compiled without bitcode actually in it.

Comment: you can change it and the again build the project then it work and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

All the frameworks you use in your project must be compiled with bitcode on in order to have a bitcode enabled project. Otherwise you will get an error. Frameworks compiled without bitcode cannot be converted to frameworks with bitcode, you must recompile them. If all your frameworks are copiled with bitcode, also enable bitcode in your project and everything should be fine.

Comment: I am aware of it. please tell how to add it to project

Comment: Well you add them as you add any other framework. Remove the current one and add the one with bitcode instead. To compile a framework with bitcode select the target you use for compiling in `Project settings` and go to `Build settings` and enable bitcode. Then compile the framework and put it in your project. If your framework code is already in your project you only have to change the setting from the framework's `project settings`.

Comment: Enabling BitCode does not **ADD** bitcode to the project.

Comment: Yes it does. Why do you say it does not?

Comment: Well I am facing this: Built an Framework and enabled BITCODE YES in that. Added that framework to other one of my projects which too have BITCODE ENABLED. error comes while archiving: missing bitcode, your framework wasn't complied _full bitcode_

Comment: Something is wrong with you framework compilation. Please make sure you set `Enable Bitcode ` to `YES` in the target that you use to compile the library (not other target). Also make sure that you add the newly compiled framework to your project. Make sure that you deleted the old ones from `Link binary with libraries` and that all your libraries from your project are compiled this way. Make sure that bitcode is enabled for the build configuration you use (debug/realease).

Comment: okay i will carefully follow that as well. Plus I did something like setting c/c++ and other linker flags to -fembed-bitcode. Can you tell whats that for and hows that different from only enabling bitcode. Thanks:)

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between ` -fembed-bitcode` and just enabling bitcode. What enabling bitcode does is actually adding that flag, so you are passing is twice if you use both approaches.

Comment: okay thanks, I was actually doing that so every time Xcode compiles , it must emits bit-code otherwise it only does during archiving i guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can set bitcode no as in image display [image]

Comment: I don't want to set it to NO. Infact i want to use BitCode.